# Django - "ManyToMany" without primary key (AutoField)

Tags: django, many-to-many

Is it even possible to create a model (or a many to many relation) in Django without id field (AutoField) in database?

For example, I have models: **Task** and **User**. User can have assigned many Tasks and Task can be assigned to many Users.
Generally, Django will create the relationship table with fields like **id**, **user_id**, **task_id**. Can a **id** field be omitted? The **user_id** and **task_id** fields will be marked as **unique_together**.

Comment: Yes, you could. But for what purpose? It makes things more complicated without any gain.

Comment: Imho to prevent **id** increasing due by removing and adding a relation

Comment: And why is that important?

Comment: Hmm, just _hypothetically_, to prevent the overflow of id or smth (if this can happen)

Comment: @DanielRoseman Imagine that you want to store availability dates of a repeating event, these dates are changing and it's cheaper to remove all of them and add all new on event update than to check for existing, delete those that you won't use and create new ones. If you have a popular service your ID will grow fastly and some day you will get a problem... and bigint won't help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is not possible to create a many to many field with just the `user_id` and `task_id` fields.

[All Django models must have exactly one primary key field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/models/#automatic-primary-key-fields). It is not yet possible to use composite primary keys (e.g. (`user_id`, `task_id`)).